# Connections. OLEDBConnection .CommandText import matches no export error

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a test sub to check and see if I can refresh my SQL Connection Query that populates a table in excel:

```
Sub UpdateQueryString2()
   
    Debug.Print "here"
    
     Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
     Dim oledbCn As OLEDBConnection
     
     Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
 
    
    For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        Debug.Print conn.Name
    Next conn
     With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - allActiveEquipmentID").OLEDBConnection
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM qAllEquipmentInfo"
        .Refresh
         Debug.Print .CommandText
    End With
    
    
    
 End Sub
```

When I go to the connections tab there are 3 connections that are showing:

[image]

Everything is good so far. As you can see from the code the connection that is highlighted in blue is the one that I am trying to change.

The first part of the code that loops through all connections and prints it prints this which is also expected and good:
[image]

Howerver, once it moves past the `.Refresh` part of the code this is the error that it throws:

[image]

The code continues without error once I hit ok and even prints the new Command text:
[image]

However, the table in the excel does not change, and if I try to refresh the connection it shows this error:

[image]

I can click load to which gives me this:

[image]

and then this:

[image]

It then adds a new column of data but still uses the old SQL Query. Everything seems to stem from the "import matches no export" error message but I cannot get much help from that error because apparently the new Microsoft Power BI also throws the same error and even when I explicitly state "Excel VBA" with the error it still shows Power BI for me.

Comment: I thought about the error message more and thought maybe the SQL should only have one column like this `SELECT ID FROM qAllEquipmentInfo`  but that still throws the same error